# How do I setup Public-Key Authentication?

Tags: linux, ssh, private-key, public-key

How do I setup Public-Key Authentication for SSH?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you have SSH installed, you should be able to run..

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then go through the steps, you'll have two files, `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (the first is your private key, the second is your public key - the one you copy to remote machines)

Then, connect to the remote machine you want to login to, to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` add the contents of your that `id_rsa.pub` file.

Oh, and `chmod 600` all the `id_rsa*` files (both locally and remote), so no other users can read them:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
```

Similarly, ensure the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is `chmod 600` also:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then, when you do `ssh remote.machine`, it should ask you for the key's password, not the remote machine.

---

To make it nicer to use, you can use `ssh-agent` to hold the decrypted keys in memory - this means you don't have to type your keypair's password every single time. To launch the agent, you run (including the back-tick quotes, which eval the output of the `ssh-agent` command)

```
`ssh-agent`
```

On some distros, ssh-agent is started automatically. If you run `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and it shows a path (probably in /tmp/) it's already setup, so you can skip the previous command.

Then to add your key, you do

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and enter your passphrase. It's stored until you remove it (using the `ssh-add -D` command, which removes all keys from the agent)

Comment: If you have to create the .ssh folder don't set it to 600 like me or you're gonna have a bad time. Instead set it to 700. :-)

Comment: Can I login from unknown machine using the private key that was generated for known/configured client to communicate to server? I mean, is this private key portable & could be used to authenticate myself to server from other machines, in case of emergency needs ??

Comment: @user01 Yes, you can copy the private key to multiple systems and access another server that has the corresponding public key.

Comment: @Charlie Gorichanaz: Is it also the other way round, like could I generate a key pair on server & use generated public key on all the other machines that I want to connect to this server ?

Comment: Uploading public key to remote machine can also be handled by `ssh-copy-id [-i identity] [user@]host` executed on local machine.

Comment: @user01 if you generate a key pair on server and copy the public key to other machines, then you’ll only be able to log in _from the server to that machines,_ not the other way round.

Answer (score 5):

For windows [this](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter8.html) is a good introduction and guide

Here are some good ssh-agents for systems other than linux.

- Windows - [pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
- OS X - [SSHKeychain](http://www.askbjoernhansen.com/2005/01/07/sshkeychain_ssh.html)