# Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine

Tags: bash, ssh, csh

This is a follow-on question to the [How do you use ssh in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061/how-do-you-use-ssh-in-a-shell-script) question.  If I want to execute a command on the remote machine that runs in the background on that machine, how do I get the ssh command to return?  When I try to just include the ampersand (&) at the end of the command it just hangs.  The exact form of the command looks like this:

```
ssh user@target "cd /some/directory; program-to-execute &"
```

Any ideas?  One thing to note is that logins to the target machine always produce a text banner and I have **SSH** keys set up so no password is required.

Answer (score 387, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
nohup myprogram > foo.log 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
```

---

The syntax and unusual use of `< /dev/null` are explained especially well [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956266/23), quoted here for your convenience.

> `< /dev/null` is used to instantly send EOF to the program, so that it
> doesn't wait for input (`/dev/null`, the null device, is a special file
> that discards all data written to it, but reports that the write
> operation succeeded, and provides no data to any process that reads
> from it, yielding EOF immediately).
>
> So the command:
>
> ```
> nohup myscript.sh >myscript.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
> #\__/             \___________/ \__/ \________/ ^
> # |                    |          |      |      |
> # |                    |          |      |  run in background
> # |                    |          |      |
> # |                    |          |   don't expect input
> # |                    |          |   
> # |                    |        redirect stderr to stdout
> # |                    |           
> # |                    redirect stdout to myscript.log
> # |
> # keep the command running 
> # no matter whether the connection is lost or you logout
> ```
>
> will move to background the command, outputting both stdout and
> stderr to myscript.log without waiting for any input.

---

See also the wikipedia artcle on [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), also quoted here for your convenience.

> Nohuping backgrounded jobs is for
> example useful when logged in via SSH,
> since backgrounded jobs can cause the
> shell to hang on logout due to a race
> condition. This problem can also
> be overcome by redirecting all three
> I/O streams.

Comment: Those files are created in the current directory. So the limit is the amount of free space on the partition. Of course you can also redirect to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Any ideas on backgrounding the process after it's finished asking for prompts? (like a gpg --decrypt that's finished asking for the password)

Comment: Trying to start a resque worker in the background using nohup, but it doesn;t work.. :(

Comment: I used this solution to start jboss using plink

Comment: @Jax, is the `&` necessary? It only works for me without it; oddly it does detach from the long running job. Here's my command: `ssh -t user@server "cd apps/myapp && nohup make my-make-target > myapp.log 2>&1 < /dev/null"`.

Comment: Ok, I figured out it was the `-t` on my ssh that was causing this.

Comment: Can you please explain what `< /dev/null` mean? Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia text changed a bit (though still discusses it); the detailed reference is http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html

Comment: It seems your answer works for most of the cases. However, for google-chrome, it fails. I mean `ssh -n server 'nohup google-chome http://google.com 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &' `

Comment: Are you sure `nohup` is needed? I'm getting good results by running the process in the background and redirecting its output to files like `ssh "myprogram >foo.out 2>foo.err &"`.

Comment: Also from the wikipedia article on nohup: "Also note that a closing SSH session does not always send a HUP signal to depending processes. Among others, this depends on whether a pseudo-terminal was allocated or not." So while strictly the nohup might not always be needed, you're better long term with it than without.

Comment: Oh, you're so great!! I'm fighting with it for above 1 hour, thanks! Finally, your answer fixed it.

Comment: @QianChen `< /dev/null` is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956266/336184 as avoiding of input wait

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? As far as I know, `/dev/null` can't be used for input, only for output. For input, it would eventually be `/dev/zero`. But according to my tests you don't need the input redirection at all.

Comment: I believe `/dev/zero` would return an infinite series of zeros as your input, which is definitely not what you want in this context. I haven't seen any documentation that says you're not allowed to use `/dev/null` for input, and in fact have seen several references to the fact that it always returns EOF, which is exactly what we want in this case. I believe if it's required or not will come down to the specific shell being triggered on the other end of your ssh connection, but I'd welcome a better explanation from someone more familiar.

Answer (score 286):

This has been the cleanest way to do it for me:-

```
ssh -n -f user@host "sh -c 'cd /whereever; nohup ./whatever > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

The only thing running after this is the actual command on the remote machine

Comment: `-n` is not needed as `-f` implies `-n`

Comment: `ssh -f` leaves the ssh process connected, just backgrounded.  The /dev/null solutions allow ssh to disconnect quickly, which might be preferable.

Comment: This solution works also for sending commands via ssh to a Syonology NAS

Comment: I need the results of "ls -l" to show up on my remote, this command does not do it.

Comment: @Siddharth Then redirect to some named file rather than /dev/null.

Comment: On OpenWrt, `nohup` is not installed by default, but this seems to work: `ssh user@host "sh -c 'command1; command2' >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &"` (without `-f` as Beni noted).

Answer (score 41):

### Redirect fd's

Output needs to be redirected with `&>/dev/null` which redirects both stderr and stdout to /dev/null and is a synonym of `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` or `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

### Parantheses

The best way is to use `sh -c '( ( command ) & )'` where command is anything.

```
ssh askapache 'sh -c "( ( nohup chown -R ask:ask /www/askapache.com &>/dev/null ) & )"'
```

### Nohup Shell

You can also use nohup directly to launch the shell:

```
ssh askapache 'nohup sh -c "( ( chown -R ask:ask /www/askapache.com &>/dev/null ) & )"'
```

### Nice Launch

Another trick is to use nice to launch the command/shell:

```
ssh askapache 'nice -n 19 sh -c "( ( nohup chown -R ask:ask /www/askapache.com &>/dev/null ) & )"'
```

Comment: I know this is a very old answer of yours, but could you add some comments on why the parentheses way is the best way, what (if any) difference adding `nohup` makes, and why and when you would use `nice`? I think that would add a lot to this answer.

Comment: Maybe to partly answer this: With nohup, you don't need to append the & to the command to be run.

Answer (score 27):

If you don't/can't keep the connection open you could use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), if you have the rights to install it.

```
user@localhost $ screen -t remote-command
user@localhost $ ssh user@target # now inside of a screen session
user@remotehost $ cd /some/directory; program-to-execute &
```

To detach the screen session: <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

To list screen sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

To reattach a session:

```
screen -d -r remote-command
```

Note that screen can also create multiple shells within each session.  A similar effect can be achieved with [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

```
user@localhost $ tmux
user@localhost $ ssh user@target # now inside of a tmux session
user@remotehost $ cd /some/directory; program-to-execute &
```

To detach the tmux session: <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

To list screen sessions:

```
tmux list-sessions
```

To reattach a session:

```
tmux attach <session number>
```

The default tmux control key, '<kbd>ctrl-b</kbd>', is somewhat difficult to use but there are several example tmux configs that ship with tmux that you can try.

Comment: how would one use `screen` for this?

Answer (score 22):

I just wanted to show a working example that you can cut and paste:

```
ssh REMOTE "sh -c \"(nohup sleep 30; touch nohup-exit) > /dev/null &\""
```

Comment: Very helpful. THanks.

Comment: Nice because only example showing outer command wrapped in double-quotes, and inner double-quotes escaped. This is almost necessary if invoking the command from PowerShell, where variables are interpolated only from within double-quotes and never from within single quotes.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this without nohup:

```sh
ssh user@host 'myprogram >out.log 2>err.log &'
```

Comment: This is a very under-rated answer, thank you!

Comment: The only change I would suggest making to this answer is `</dev/null` so we can't block on stdin either.

Comment: this will never work as intended (what the op asked for). the shell (and thus ssh) will wait for the backgrounded process to terminate.

Answer (score 9):

Quickest and easiest way is to use the 'at' command:

```sh
ssh user@target "at now -f /home/foo.sh"
```

Comment: This would be a great general solution if `at` accepted command line arguments after the time and not only from a file.

Comment: You can simulate a file with <<< like in: ssh user@target "at now -f <<< 'my_comnads'"

Comment: Involving a separate daemon (and using tooling that won't work unless that daemon is running) seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity for something that [doesn't _require_ an extra daemon at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60437534/14122).

Answer (score 8):

I think you'll have to combine a couple of these answers to get what you want. If you use nohup in conjunction with the semicolon, and wrap the whole thing in quotes, then you get:

```
ssh user@target "cd /some/directory; nohup myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null"
```

which seems to work for me. With nohup, you don't need to append the & to the command to be run. Also, if you don't need to read any of the output of the command, you can use

```
ssh user@target "cd /some/directory; nohup myprogram > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

to redirect all output to /dev/null.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me may times:

```
ssh -x remoteServer "cd yourRemoteDir; ./yourRemoteScript.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this...

```
sudo /home/script.sh -opt1 > /tmp/script.out &
```

Comment: Perfect, works with a PuTTY SSH session. I can exit and the script continues on the machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It appeared quite convenient for me to have a *remote* tmux session using the `tmux new -d <shell cmd>` syntax like this:

```sh
ssh someone@elsewhere 'tmux new -d sleep 600'
```

This will launch new session on `elsewhere` host and ssh command on local machine will return to shell almost instantly. You can then ssh to the remote host and `tmux attach` to that session. Note that there's nothing about local tmux running, only remote!

Also, if you want your session to persist after the job is done, simply add a shell launcher after your command, but don't forget to enclose in quotes:

```sh
ssh someone@elsewhere 'tmux new -d "~/myscript.sh; bash"'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you run remote command without allocating tty, redirect `stdout/stderr` works, `nohup` is not necessary.

   `ssh user@host 'background command &>/dev/null &'`
2. If you use `-t` to allocate tty to run interactive command along with background command, and background command is the last command, like this:

   `ssh -t user@host 'bash -c "interactive command; nohup backgroud command &>/dev/null &"'`

   It's possible that `background command` doesn't actually start. There's race here:

   1. `bash` exits after `nohup` starts. As a session leader, `bash` exit results in `HUP` signal sent to `nohup` process.
   2. `nohup` ignores `HUP` signal.

   If `1` completes before `2`, the `nohup` process will exit and won't start the `background command` at all. We need to wait `nohup` start the `background command`. A simple workaroung is to just add a `sleep`:

   `ssh -t user@host 'bash -c "interactive command; nohup backgroud command &>/dev/null & sleep 1"'`

The question was asked and answered years ago, I don't know if openssh behavior changed since then. I was testing on:
`OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, whenever I need to run a command on a remote machine that's complicated, I like to put the command in a script on the destination machine, and just run that script using ssh.

For example:

```
# simple_script.sh (located on remote server)

#!/bin/bash

cat /var/log/messages | grep <some value> | awk -F " " '{print $8}'
```

And then I just run this command on the source machine:

```
ssh user@ip "/path/to/simple_script.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, but with the added complexity that I was trying to do it from Java.  So on one machine running java, I was trying to run a script on another machine, in the background (with nohup).

From the command line, here is what worked: (you may not need the "-i keyFile" if you don't need it to ssh to the host)

```
ssh -i keyFile user@host bash -c "\"nohup ./script arg1 arg2 > output.txt 2>&1 &\""
```

Note that to my command line, there is one argument after the "-c", which is all in quotes.  But for it to work on the other end, it still needs the quotes, so I had to put escaped quotes within it.

From java, here is what worked:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("ssh", "-i", "keyFile", "bash", "-c",
 "\"nohup ./script arg1 arg2 > output.txt 2>&1 &\"");
Process process = b.start();
// then read from process.getInputStream() and close it.
```

It took a bit of trial & error to get this working, but it seems to work well now.

Comment: Why do you have literal quotes inside the argument following `-c`? I don't see how that could possibly work. It's like `ssh -i keyFile bash -c '"nohup ./script arg1 arg2 > output.txt 2>&1 &"'` in bash, which doesn't work either and for the same reason (incorrect literal quotes nested inside the necessary and correct syntactic ones).

Answer (score 0):

```
YOUR-COMMAND &> YOUR-LOG.log &
```

This should run the command and assign a process id you can simply tail -f YOUR-LOG.log to see results written to it as they happen.  you can log out anytime and the process will carry on

Comment: `&>your-log.log` only works if the remote system's shell is bash (or otherwise has the extension at hand). If it could possibly be sh, `>your-log.log 2>&1` is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh then use `program-to-execute &!` is a zsh-specific shortcut to both background and disown the process, such that exiting the shell will leave it running.

Answer (score 0):

A follow-on to @cmcginty's concise working example which also shows how to alternatively wrap the outer command in double quotes. This is how the template would look if invoked from within a `PowerShell` script (which can only interpolate variables from within double-quotes and ignores any variable expansion when wrapped in single quotes):

```
ssh user@server "sh -c `"($cmd) &>/dev/null </dev/null &`""
```

Inner double-quotes are escaped with back-tick instead of backslash. This allows `$cmd` to be composed by the `PowerShell` script, e.g. for deployment scripts and automation and the like. `$cmd` can even contain a multi-line `heredoc` if composed with unix `LF`.

Answer (score -2):

First follow this procedure:

Log in on A as user a and generate a pair of authentication keys. Do not enter a passphrase:

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A
```

Now use ssh to create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on B. (The directory may already     exist, which is fine):

```
a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
b@B's password:
```

Finally append a's new public key to b@B:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter b's password one last time:

```
a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
b@B's password:
```

From now on you can log into B as b from A as a without password:

```
a@A:~> ssh b@B
```

then this will work without entering a password

ssh b@B "cd /some/directory; program-to-execute &"

Comment: The question says that dagorym already set the keys up to not require a password, but it's still hanging

Answer (score -3):

I think this is what you need:
At first you need to install `sshpass` on your machine.
then you can write your own script:

```
while read pass port user ip; do
sshpass -p$pass ssh -p $port $user@$ip <<ENDSSH1
    COMMAND 1
    .
    .
    .
    COMMAND n
ENDSSH1
done <<____HERE
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP    
____HERE
```