# call matlab in an ssh command from a perl script

Tags: perl, matlab, batch-file, ssh, background

Hi i have set up passwordless ssh set up and have perl call `ssh -o "BatchMode yes" user@host "runMe.pl arg1 arg2"`

runMe.pl calls matlab and the function run_online with the given args.

`nohup matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -r "run_online('$imgfolder/$folder/', '$ARGV[0]$folder', '/homes/rbise/results/mitosis/$ARGV[0]/$folder/')" > out.txt < /dev/null &`

for some reason matlab never starts running. why is this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is substantially a duplicate of the [[perl] question that was asked immediately previously to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097083/perl-fork-doesnt-work-properly-when-ran-remotely-via-ssh) -- at least, the answer is the same. You have no controlling terminal when you connect with ssh. Try `ssh -o "BatchMode yes" user@host "bash -c runMe.pl arg1 arg2"`.