# Use SSH to start a background process on a remote server, and exit session

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-server, nohup

I am using SSH to start a background process on a remote server. This is what I have at the moment:

> ssh remote_user@server.com "nohup process &"

This works, in that the process does start. But the SSH session itself does not end until I hit Ctr-C.

When I hit Ctr-C, the remote process continues to run in the background.

I would like to place the ssh command in a script that I can run locally, so I would like the ssh session to exit automatically once the remote process has started.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 48):

The "-f" option to ssh tells ssh to run the remote command in the background and to return immediately. E.g.,

```
ssh -f user@host "echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar"
```

If you type the above, you will get your shell prompt back immediately, you will then see "foo" output. Five seconds later you will then see "bar" output. In the meantime, you could have been using the shell.

Comment: Note that this will keep your SSH session running in the background.  If the session is disconnected the command will stop running.

Answer (score 37):

When using `nohup`, make sure you also redirect stdin, stdout and stderr:

```
ssh user@server 'DISPLAY=:0 nohup xeyes < /dev/null > std.out 2> std.err &'
```

In this way you will be completely detached from the remote process. Be carefull with using `ssh -f user@host...` since that will only put the ssh process in the background on the *calling* side. You can verify this by running a `ps -aux | grep ssh` on the calling machine and this will show you that the ssh call is still active, but just put in the background.

In my example above I use `DISPLAY=:0` since xeyes is an X11 program and I want it started on the *remote* machine.

Comment: It worked for my with a forked process like '''rsync --daemon''' that wouldn't exit otherwise

Comment: This method is great when you fork your script during execution. My ssh was not exiting even after the script I executed was finished. I spent whole my day to somehow fix it. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Is it necessary to redirect `stdin` to `/dev/null`? Is it necessary to invoke `nohup` via SSH? I think SSH does not send HUP anyway. I didn't find any difference with `ssh user@server "process &>/dev/null &"`

Answer (score 5):

You could use `screen` to run your process on this screen, detach from screen `Ctrl-a :detach` and exit your current session without problem. Then you can reconnect to SSH and attach to this screen again to continue with your task or check if is finished.

Or you can send the command to an already running screen. Your local script should look like this:

```
ssh remote_user@server.com
screen -dmS new_screen sh
screen -S new_screen -p 0 -X stuff $'nohup process \n'
exit
```

For more info see this [tutorial](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)

Comment: Somethink like this? `ssh remote_user@server.com 'screen -S world/ -X stuff "nohup process "'`

Comment: These didn't quite work for my problem, but I found another article that matched my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine

Answer (score -1):

Well this question is almost 10 years old, but I recently had to launch a very long script (taking several hours to complete) on a remote server and I found a way using the crontab.

If can edit your user's crontab on the remote server, connect with ssh to the server, edit the crontab and add an entry that will start your script the next minute. Let's say it's 15h03. Add this line :

```
4 15 * * * /path/to/your/script.sh
```

save your crontab, wait a minute for the script to be launched. Then edit again your crontab to remove this entry.

You can then safely exit ssh, even shut down your computer while the script is running.