# Run command on server using Plink and keep it running after disconnecting

Tags: python, shell, batch-file, ssh, plink

I have a Raspberry Pi which I use to play a video on a loop. I have a button which I use to end the video to display the desktop wallpaper which I have as a static image.

To do this I use a simple Python script that launches `omxplayer` and loops waiting for the button to be pressed, when pressed it kills `omxplayer`, waits a while then re-starts the loop.

This all works fine.

I am wanting to use `plink` to launch this script from a Windows machine, and have used the following:

```
plink.exe -ssh pi@192.168.0.201 -pw ****** "sudo python /home/pi/ftp/files/button.py"
```

This launches the script no problem, but because the script does not 'end' the batch file just sits there.

I have other batch files using `plink` to kill the script and others to turn the monitor on & off using CEC all of which work fine because `plink` gets a return, but because the Python script runs indefinitely there is nothing returned, so `plink` just seems to hang.

So..Question is, can `plink` be told to send the command and terminate, regardless of response, or (and I've  looked for this with no joy) is there a way of setting a timeout for plink to give up waiting for a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (not sure), you want plink to start the the script on the server and exit (keeping the script running).

The `plink` is just an alternative SSH client, similar to OpenSSH `ssh`. So just use the same techniques you will find on Internet for `ssh`.

Two of zillions of questions on this topic:

- [How to run a command in background using ssh and detach the session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628204/850848)
- [Use SSH to start a background process on a remote server, and exit session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19996089/850848)

Comment: Of  course I never thought of it like that - I was thinking of plink having it's own methods rather than it just being a  front for SSH. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For anyone else, I found the 2nd link didn't work (the -f option) as this was not recognised by plink, but the first option (nohup) worked faultlessly.