# Resume in PowerShell 5.1 if exe doesn't finish

Tags: powershell, plink

I am using a loop (`ForEach-Object`) in a PowerShell script to connect to different hosts via plink (PuTTY).

```
plink -ssh $_ -l $user -pw $password -T -batch $command
```

`$_` is the IP address of the host.

The command does an upgrade on the remote host. After the upgrade, the remote host reboots, but the connection doesn't close. So plink/PowerShell waits endlessly. How can I get PowerShell to resume the script?

Comment: `plink` is very good and works. Is there a reason not to use PowerShell Remoting? `help about_Remote`

Answer (score 1):

- You can solve this either on local/PowerShell side by aborting stalled command:
  [Powershell Start Process, Wait with Timeout, Kill and Get Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36933527/850848)
- Or on remote side (assuming Linux), by running the command on background:
  [Run command on server using Plink and keep it running after disconnecting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73228082/850848)

---

*You will find dozens of other questions here for both approaches.*