# Multiple nohup process writing output to same file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to run multiple background processes through `ssh`, aggregate all outputs and errors to the same file and redirect the logs to papertrail using [remote_syslog](https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog)

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine) i execute a ruby script in background like this :

```
ssh deploy@xx.xx.xxx.xx 'cd path/to/my_app; nohup ruby my_script.rb > log/script.log 2> log/script.log < /dev/null &'
```

It works as long as i only run one script. If i run multiple scripts i only see the output of the first script in the log file.

Can you explain what i'm doing wrong ? Or provide a better way to achieve this. Thanks !

(the log file is in `path/to/my_app/log/script.log`)

---

**Solution :**

Thanks to devnull comment i solved it, it was so simple... The proper command is :

```
ssh deploy@xx.xx.xxx.xx 'cd path/to/my_app; nohup ruby my_script.rb >> log/script.log 2>> log/script.log < /dev/null &'
```

Comment: Looks like you want to _append_ the output.  Use `>>` instead of `>`.