# How can I make the Ant task "SSHExec" run a command and exit before it's completed?

Tags: ant

I have an ant build script that connects to a remote server and kicks off a local build using [SSHExec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html).  This build takes approximately 1 minute and it sends me an email when it's completed, but the ant task I have:

```
<sshexec
   host="${deploy.host}"
   username="${deploy.username}"
   trust="true"
   keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa"
   command="~/updateGit.sh"/>
```

Will wait until the script is completed.  I tried passing a `&` like so (I assume I have to escape it in a build.xml):

```
<sshexec
   host="${deploy.host}"
   username="${deploy.username}"
   trust="true"
   keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa"
   command="~/updateGit.sh &amp;"/>
```

But this doesn't seem to make a difference.  In case this extra detail helps anyone, the script generates a lot of output and a slow internet connection can cause the script to take a lot longer (as it's output is being piped back, the assumption with this approach is that I only care about the output after its done, so if I pack it up into an email I can monitor my inbox as builds get kicked off, basically it's a poor-man's Continuous Integration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29172/16959) (and the `nohup` command) I updated my task as follows:

```
<sshexec
  host="${deploy.host}"
  username="${deploy.username}"
  trust="true"
  keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa"
  command="nohup ~/updateGit.sh &gt; /dev/null 2&gt; error.log &lt; /dev/null &amp;"/>
```