# Run a command remotely on ec2 using aws-cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'd like to create a bash script using aws cli that

- start an ec2 image
- clone a github repo
- build a docker image
- stops the ec2 image.

I managed to make the start and stop using
aws ec2 start-instances and aws ec2 stop-instances
But I am struggling to run the other bash commands.
I saw this: [Run a command remotely on ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297684/run-a-command-remotely-on-ec2)
That explains how to run a bash command.

So I tried:

```
aws ssm send-command \
--instance-ids "i-02ae********" \
--region "us-east-2"\
--document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
--parameters commands="git clone https://myrepo.git" \
--output text
```

But I get as output

```
COMMAND 77821510-9094-4d3d-b7c0-99a9d0c46716            0       0       AWS-RunShellScript      $DEFAULT        0       2022-08-07T01:04:19.705000+02:00        50      0                       us-east-2       2022-08-06T23:04:19.705000+02:00                Pending Pending 1       3600
CLOUDWATCHOUTPUTCONFIG          False
INSTANCEIDS     i-02aef7e********
NOTIFICATIONCONFIG              
COMMANDS        git clone https://github.com/myrepo.git
```

And if I ssh into the ec2 instance, I don't see any effect of the command.
Can someone give me some hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you checked the logs in `/var/log/amazon/ssm`? What if you tried specifying `--working-directory /root` or some directory and then see if the clone happens inside `/root`?

Comment: Check the directory of ssm user, I tried this and I do see that repo is cloned to the directory : /var/snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656. Or you can simple log in using session manager and do ls to check if the repo is cloned.

Comment: ooh! that was the problem, the clone is done in /var/snap/amazon-ssm-agent, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Why not just pass those commands to the EC2 instance as `user-data` since you want it to  at startup?

Comment: @MarkB it's harder to monitor user-data. Anyway, Systems Manager have ability to make this 4 steps in one job, so I assume OP is using it with automation

Comment: Exactly, doing it in the user-data  makes it very static, and then I have to use more tricks to get parameters for the startup-script. Instead using the system manager I can make a script in python that is more versatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send-command` executing an asynchronous execution. In the response, you have information about status of your command - `pending`.
You can monitor the status of your execution using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-command-invocation.html

Btw, you can always find your command execution, with logs, in the AWS console - `SSM` service -> `run command`. There you will find the answer to your question.

Btw2, it is strongly recommended to don't use SSH, if you can use Systems Manager - I assume it is possible in you're case, because you can use `send-command` API, so `start-session` should be allowed as well.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/start-session.html

Comment: Yes, I am using indeed System manager with boto3. The point is that  I was not finding the results of those actions. But as @X-men said, it is because the syster manger user have their own workspace. Now I found it

Answer (score 0):

For the start and stop portion...

If you want to run a script *every* time that an Amazon EC2 instance starts, simply place the script in:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

Any script in that directory will run every time that the instance boots.

When the script has finished processing, run:

```
sudo shutdown now -h
```

This will shutdown the instance from *within* the instance, rather than having to call an AWS API.

For more details, see: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: The problem is that in this way the script has to be static, I need at least to be able to change parameters

Comment: There are many ways to pass values. Some ideas: Put a file in S3; put values in the instance User Data (it's doesn't have to be a script!); send a message to an SQS queue; set a Tag on the instance; store a value in Parameter Store. I'd suggest storing it in S3 and the script can use the AWS CLI `aws s3 cp` command to download the configuration file.

Comment: Recommended by aws is to always use Parameter store, and never store the configuration in the S3 bucket... Btw, I updated my previous answer - sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Yes, Parameter Store would be excellent for storing a static configuration (eg database passwords, server names) but it would not be a good approach for passing variables that are specific to a job to be performed, especially if there might be multiple jobs running in parallel.