# Launching multiple processes on different boxes with BASH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, process

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

myProgram1&
pidMyProgram1=$!

ssh myUserName@pluto
myProgram2&
pidMyProgram2=$!

function cleanup
{
   kill -9 $pidMyProgram1 $pidMyProgram2
   exit 0
}

trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM

while :
do
   sleep 1
done
```

It does not work as I need it to. I am trying to launch two processes, one on another box called pluto. I want these two processes to run indefinitely until I hit control+c, then I want both processes to stop. When I run this I end up ssh'ed into pluto, but my processes aren't even running. Any ideas as to how I can handle my requirement of starting the process on a seperate box? I am pretty new to BASH...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine)

Comment: I don't agree with this being a duplicate question. There are other factors, like using trap to cleanup the processes on those seperate machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was ssh -l username hostname 'pkill processName'

It finally works!

Answer (score 1):

`ssh myUserName@pluto` starts a shell on the remote machine  and *does not* exit until that shell exits. It does not cause the remainder of your script to be executed on the remote machine. You just need to pass `myProgram2` as an argument to `ssh`; that program must exist on the remote machine, not just on the local box.

```
myProgram1 & pidMyProgram1=$!

ssh myUserName@pluto myProgram2 & pidMyProgram2=$!

function cleanup
{
   kill $pidMyProgram1 $pidMyProgram2
   exit 0
}

trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM

while :
do
   sleep 1
done
```

Assuming `myProgram1` will run forever until interrupted, you can replace the busy `while` loop with

```
wait $pidMyProgram1
```

Comment: When I run my script I get a no such process message from Bash for the process that I created after using ssh. Is there another way to obtain the correct PID?

Comment: They should be correct. It's possible that the programs are exiting naturally before `cleanup` is called, though.

Comment: When I ssh into the other machine the PID is definitely different. In fact, shouldn't I have to ssh into that machine to close the PID?

Comment: If you kill `ssh`, the process running on the remote hosts should receive `SIGHUP` and exit as well.

Comment: Could you update your answer to address the concern of getting the correct PID and making sure it is closed on exit? I am not getting it still.

Comment: When you kill `ssh`, the connection to the remote machine is closed, and the program that was running receives `SIGHUP` and exits as a result. You don't need the process ID of that program, because you only need the local process ID of the `ssh` in order to kill it.