# How to run a webserver script on remote server through SSH?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, server

I am currently hosting a couple servers on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 server. By default, the server doesn't have a GUI, but I installed one along with xRDP.

If I run the script from the terminal, it will continuously run **until** the terminal is closed. **But**, if I run the script by simply double clicking it, it will run in the background and keep running regardless of whether the terminal window is open.

This is a problem, because with xRDP sessions, when they close, the running windows in that session close as well. I want to be able to start and stop the servers using SSH, instead of having to manually remote desktop in.

I have a way to easily kill the servers: `sudo killall -v python2.7`, and I can do this via SSH easily. The problem is, I cannot open the scripts for starting each server, because when I do, it runs the server in the terminal instance that is created on *my* computer. When I close that instance, the server closes as well.

So the basic, TL;DR version is that I want to be able to run a script **in the background** via ssh. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Justin

Comment: You shouldn't be starting your server processes via scripts. You should create them under a proper management system like upstart or systemd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine)

Comment: @DanielRoseman The servers are still under development, thus making them unstable. I like to be able to start and restart them as I please.

Comment: I feel as though they were asking a different question, @tripleee. The answer below was perfect for what I needed!

Comment: @Schwaitz how is this not an exact duplicate of the linked question? How can you say it is a different question? It is asking exactly the same thing, and the answer you have marked as accepted is even one of the answers to that question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use for things like this is the `screen` command putting my command in a disconnected screen session.  I can connect to it later if I need to.

Comment: Works like a charm! I used `screen -S session_name -d -m <commands here>` and it worked perfectly.