# prevent AWS EMR ssh connection timeout

Tags: ssh

I have a cron job run on local server. I would like to use it to

1. start a new EMR cluster
2. trigger a Spark model training job on the cluster
   like this `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i xxx.pem hadoop@10.10.x.xxxx "bash ~/train_model.sh"`. Since the EMR cluster is new every time, use `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"` flag to avoid new host check.
3. finally shut down the EMR cluster.

The problem is the the model training takes 10+hrs and the ssh connection in step2 **timeout** every time.

By searching around, I find it might be resolved by editing ssh config on EMR cluster master node, but since the EMR cluster is new every time so I have to also do the edit every time. I am interesting to find out if there is a more neat way?

Comment: Run your script on the background, not directly run.

Comment: And this is pure ssh problem not emr related, so I deleted the tag of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine)