# How to run npx command in background?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npx

I want to know how can I run an npm package in background, like a server package which is my case.

I am trying to run an [FTP server package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv) from npm using npx directly as it's useful to use packages without installing them locally or even globally.

What I am doing right now is:

`npx ftp-srv ftp://0.0.0.0:2121 --username USER_NAME --password PASSWORD --read-only --root ./logs &`

From within the sever, and I wanted to keep it running after I close my ssh connection. This is not for production use, I just wanted to have an FTP server running to get my logs right away for an application I am doing for myself.

I am running that on an AWS Ubuntu instance: *Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1051-aws 86_64)*

Comment: This should be a comment, but I have low rep -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine

Comment: No probs, good option, similar to screen