# How does running ssh with a command string work behind the scene?

Tags: ssh

I have some difficulities on understanding how `ssh` works behind the scene when I run it with a command string.

Normally, I type `ssh rick@1.2.3.4` then I am logged into the remote machine and run some commands. If I don't use `nohup` or `disown`, once I close the session, all running processes started by `ssh` will stop. That's the ordinary case.

But if I run `ssh` with a command string, things become different. **The process started by** `ssh` **won't stop if I close the session**.

For example:

1. Run from local command line: `ssh rick@1.2.3.4 "while true; do echo \"123test\" >> sshtest.txt"; done`
2. Run a remote script `ssh rick@1.2.3.4 './remoteScript_whichDoTheSameAsAbove.sh'`

After closing the session by `Ctrl + C` or `kill pid` on the local machine, on the remote machine I see the process still running with `ps -ef` .

So my question is, could someone make a short introduction on how `ssh` works when I run it with a command string like above?

---

Also, I get **very confused** when I see these 2 related questions during searching:

Q1: [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine) . What is this question asking for? Isn't `ssh rick@1.2.3.4 'some command'`  already run as a seperate shell/pts? I don't understand what "in the background" is for.

Q2: [Keep processes running after SSH session disconnects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-processes-running-after-ssh-session-disconnects) Isn't simply running a remote script meets his requirement? `ssh rick@1.2.3.4 "./remoteScript.sh`. I get very confused when I see so many "magic" answers under that question.