# Upload to ftp on change

Tags: ftp, inotify

I like the functionality of dreamweaver where you can add a site and define an ftp and then when you save a file it saves a local copy and also uploads a file via ftp. I am trying to get similar functionality with linux. What I have thought of doing is have inotify monitor a local folder and upload any new or changed files to an ftp site, but I am having a hard time finding information on this. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Also, I do not want to install any programs on the ftp server.

Thanks
Dean

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at cron scheduling an rsync job, which will efficiently copy changed files across a network at a chosen interval.   rsync will use ssh or rsh (not ftp), so this might not work, but would seem a better way in most cases.

Comment: First of all, cron, not chron. Secondly, 'rcsync will use ssh or ssh' is wrong. It can use.. Plus samba, ftp, and ... Well, that's it.. +1 anyway.

Comment: Fixed the cron misspelling.  Time for some coffee.  Being more precise on the second bit, rsync uses many protocols, but ftp/sftp isn't one of them.

Comment: Indeed, sorry about misinforming about ftp :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw together a [**python**](http://python.org/) script which uses [**inotify**](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) and [**scp**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)/[**ftp**](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html).

These are all common and should be supported by whatever distro your using. They're also all pretty well documented.