# scp using paramiko doesnt work - ssh works fine

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I have been able to use ssh and issue command in the remote server. Now I want to scp files from the remote server but that just seems like its impossible. I'm totally new to python and Paramiko. The error is permission denied in my local directory of darn windows. The files are supposed to come from the Mac. Any other really really simple example I can use to scp files from a remote Linux machine to my local Windows machine?

```
import paramiko


hostname = '192.xx.1.xx'
password = 'pop123'
username = "husbad2"
port = 22

mypath='C:\\Users\\handsonexpert\\Documents'
remotepath='/Users/ihussain/testdir/file3.txt'


t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
t.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.put(mypath, remotepath)
```

Comment: you should be using sftp.get if your aim is to retrieve the files from 192.168.1.132 into mypath.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To retrieve files from a remote host into a local directory:

```
......
localpath='C:\\Users\\handsonexpert\\Documents\\file3.txt'
remotepath='/Users/ihussain/testdir/file3.txt'
......
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
```

Comment: This is using SFTP not scp ??

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `remotepath,localpath' is this a valid error?

Answer (score 8):

You're not using `scp` here, but `SFTP` (`SFTPClient`).

If you're set on using `scp`, maybe take a look at this [paramiko scp](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py) client, there is an example of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python).

Aside, out of general security interests and programming style, *don't* hard code your password and user credentials, and especially *never* publish them in a public forum like SO. We don't need them and you don't need to post them.

Comment: `SFTP` and `FTP` are different protocols.