# Bash script transfer to Python - copy logs from server to another remote server

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have done my easy script in bash - this script should transfer the file with the specific new name from server 1 to remote server 2.

Can someone help with this and transfer all script to Python.

```
 #!/bin/bash

path=/opt/log #Im in dir /opt/log
fdate=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-1 day") # yesterday date
file=maillog-$fdate     # log from yesterday which will be transfer to remote server
cp $path/$file /tmp/$HOSTNAME-$file  # copy $file to /tmp with the specific name of $HOSTNAME + $File name
gzip /tmp/$HOSTNAME-$file      # ZIP the file

rserver=hansus@hansus.edu.net    # remote server 
rpath=/opt/log/maillog # remote path

scp /tmp/$HOSTNAME-$file.gz $rserver:$rpath # copy the file to remote server to remote path

rm /tmp/$HOSTNAME-$file.gz # clean the /tmp dir
 #Done
```

Comment: This answer might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python

Comment: Hello it was helpful but last thing I need to write instead of fdate=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-1 day") # yesterday date - is this fdate = yesterday date "date command in format +%Y%m%d - 1day, how is it possible to create this one in Python?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this.

***One option is unison:***

http://xmodulo.com/synchronize-files-between-two-servers.html

***The rsync solution:***

You will need to ssh into one of the servers first (this should be trivial). Once in you can run this.

```
rsync -rtlzv --ignore-errors -e ssh . username@hostname:/path/to/directory
```

from: http://darcynorman.net/2009/01/07/how-i-move-stuff-between-servers-with-rsync/

***The scp solution:***

I actually think this is the most elegant way because you do not have to ssh in first. Somethibng like this:

```
nohup scp alice@source:/the/answer/of/all bob@target.example.com:/var/tmp/42 &
```

from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65116/does-a-scp-transfer-close-when-i-close-the-shell