# How to use gcloud commands programmatically via Python

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

The Google documentation is a little generic on this topic and I find it hard to get around the different APIs and terms they're using, so I'm wondering if someone could point me to the right direction.

I'm looking for a way to call the `gcloud` command directly from Python. I've installed `gcloud` in my Python environment and as an example to follow, I'd like to know how to do the following from Python:

```
gcloud compute copy-files [Source directory or file name] [destination directory of file name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing magic about uploading files to a Computer Engine VM. I ended up using `paramiko` to upload files.

Answer (score 4):

You should check out `gcloud`:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcloud

Answer (score 1):

You can of course call gcloud from python directly and not care about the implementation details, or you can try to see what gcloud does:

Try running gcloud compute copy-files with the --dry-run flag. That will expose the scp command it uses underneath and with what arguments. Knowing what scp params you need, you can recreate them programmatically using paramiko_scp in python. More information on this here: [How to scp in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I answered that already yesterday. How about other commands that are not scp related? How can these be called from gloud-python?

Comment: Don't run the `gcloud` command as a subprocess from Python. Instead, use [`google-api-client-library`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) and see the relevant docs for how to use it, e.g., with [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide). If you have a specific question about a particular command or API, please clarify in a separate question.

Comment: I found the google api client library in the meantime. I was wrongly assuming that `gcloud` is also a Python library which one could access from Python, but many commands just seem to map to other commands (like `scp` for instance).

Comment: @orange once you've installed `gcloud` (aka `google-cloud-sdk`), since it's Python, you can see the source so you can find out what the implementation is for any given command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subprocess.run function in python to execute commands from your terminal/shell/bash. That is what I have done to execute gcloud commands from python, rather than using the Python SDK.