# How to move multiple files from local machine to a sever using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have a framework used to validate few test cases and results will be stored in local machine containing multiple text and images.

Need to move these files from our local host to server.

I have the sever IP address, username and password.

So using Python I need to move these files or copy it to server

Comment: Which protocol do you need to use? ssh? http? ftp?

Comment: How should the files be transfered? (S)FTP, SCP, SMB, NFS, HTTP(S), ...?

Comment: what OSs are you using, which server services are running on the server (for example ssh or ftp) that you could use to upload the files? did you already search the web for "how to transfer files between computers" or the like? what did you try and what did you investigate so far? basically, you first decide how to transfer them, and then you decide how to do that from python.

Comment: I am using Linux(both host and sever) so we can use ftp or ssh or just a cp commands

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scp in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)

Comment: Why python at all? Just `scp <all your files> username@server:/path/to/store`

Answer (score 2):

If you are going for `ssh`, you'll have to use `scp` and there is a dedicated Python package for that: `Paramiko`. [See this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python).

```
import paramiko

def createSSHClient(server, port, user, password):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, user, password)
    return client

ssh = createSSHClient(server, port, user, password)
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
scp.put([file1,file2],remotePath)
```

Of course, you have to specify the various variables according to their name. The `scp.put` [function](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py/blob/master/scp.py#L122) takes a list of local files and a destination path on the remote system as arguments.

Comment: i want to move multiple files.so if possible can i get the code

Comment: If this helps you, please act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Python problem: You say you have a username and a password to the server, but that doesn't tell us the least in which way you can access that server. Do you have SSH access? Then use `scp` as a command-line program or one of the numerous Python modules that make that possible.

The same goes for protocols like `FTP`, `WebDAV`, `cifs`/`smb`, `NFS`, ... It all depends on what ways you have to access/modify/create files on the server. Hence, this answer is all I can give you to your extremely inaccurate question.

Answer (score 0):

used SCP to do the transfer
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa intel@10.223.98.165 "mkdir < Folder created >"

scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa < source >*.txt < destination >
 using os.system()
 Thanks for helping