# SCP in python by using password

Tags: python, scp

I have been trying to do scp a file to a remote computer by using password. I used this code:

```
import os
import scp
client = scp.Client(host="104.198.152.xxx", username="nxxx", password="xxxxxx")
client.transfer("script.py", "~/script.py")
```

as it's suggested in [How to scp in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python), but it outputs:

```
File "script.py", line 5, in <module>
    client = scp.Client(host="104.198.152.153", username="nazarihome", password="mohMOH13579")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

I also tried other ways that people suggest and seems that none of them works. Does anybody have a suggestion that really works?

p.s. I have to use password not the key if your answer depends on that.

Comment: Did you try `scp.SCPClient` instead of `scp.Client` ?

Comment: You've copied an example from a question, and not the answer. Take another look at the post you based your example on.

Comment: the codes in the post you referred to are not real. it's a sort of wish list.

Answer (score 9):

The [`scp.py` GitHub page](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py) has the following example that uses itself with the [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) library for handling SSL:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect(hostname='ip', 
            port = 'port',
            username='username',
            password='password',
            pkey='load_key_if_relevant')


# SCPCLient takes a paramiko transport as its only argument
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())

scp.put('file_path_on_local_machine', 'file_path_on_remote_machine')
scp.get('file_path_on_remote_machine', 'file_path_on_local_machine')

scp.close()
```

So the actual type you want it is `scp.SCPClient`.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as Jan 2019:

Install required Python packages:

```
pip install scp
pip install paramiko
```

Include library in the code:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient
```

Wrote a function for it:

```
# SSH/SCP Directory Recursively     
def ssh_scp_files(ssh_host, ssh_user, ssh_password, ssh_port, source_volume, destination_volume):
    logging.info("In ssh_scp_files()method, to copy the files to the server")
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.connect(ssh_host, username=ssh_user, password=ssh_password, look_for_keys=False)

    with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as scp:
        scp.put(source_volume, recursive=True, remote_path=destination_volume)
```

Now call it anywhere you want in the code:

`ssh_scp_files(ssh_host, ssh_user, ssh_password, ssh_port, source_volume, destination_volume)`

If all above implemented correctly, you will see the the successful messages in the console/logs like this:

[image]