# Using python to copy files from/to raspberri pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a python script running on a NAS and picking up files from inside of a raspberry pi.

Didn't find any examples how to access raspberry pi.
Can somebody give advice?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the script copying files from the raspberry pi? Is the script sort of backing up the raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do more research.

The easiest way is probably to run Secure Copy (SCP) over SSH from python on NAS. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)

If you want to serve files to other clients (e.g. your laptop), consider running file server on RPI. Perhaps FTP: [FTP on RPI tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md) 
Otherwise you can implement HTTP like interface (REST API for example) and "get" files via HTTP. Don't skim on the security and access rights to your API.