# How to use scp command in conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, scp

I'm trying to upload some files onto a remote server but the command scp is not installed on my laptop. I'm working with Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine and the server is a Linux machine with Ubuntu 18.04.

To my intuition, I think it's easier to install scp directly with conda than to install it on Windows (I'm actually using Anaconda Prompt rather than Windows DOS), so following the instruction of Anaconda website I ran

> conda install -c remram scp

after which I reran the scp command, only to find scp still not installed.

I have double-checked other dependent tools like ssh and also updated my conda, but nothing worked.

Is it even possible to use scp on a conda environment when there isn't an scp on my computer? If so, what's the correct thing to do to make it available? If not, can anyone share a reliable way to install scp on Windows system?

Comment: question is a little unclear but, using conda install means you are downloading the scp python package not the command prompt command..if that helps

Comment: I see... then is there any recommendations on how to install scp on Windows10 easily? Many thanks!

Comment: @Jiang1926 You can try installing WinSCP but it's not the same thing. You might also want to consider installing the Linux subsystem and then run things from there.

Comment: either that ^ or just use the python pkg if you can, some instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python

Comment: i actually gave an example how to do this on a previously deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728602/how-to-send-a-file-to-a-pc-that-is-not-in-same-network-with-python/56728831#56728831

Comment: I tried using WinSCP and it worked for the time being. Thank you all~

Comment: There's also `pscp`, which is Putty's SCP client ([see docs](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.72/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp)). It's on the `anaconda` channel (so `conda install -c anaconda pscp`), though it doesn't look like the Anaconda team cares about updating it.