# I want my django app to get a file from a remote machine

Tags: django, scp

I need my django app to scp a file on a remote server into the django 'media' folder.

Is spawning an scp session with pexpect in my django app the best way to go about this?

Alternatively, are there libraries I can use in my django app to do this?

Any help is much appreciate.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scp in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)