# How to specify remote file attachment for SMTP mail in Python

Tags: python-3.x, remote-access, smtpclient, smtplib

How can the remote attachment file be specified to be included in SMTP mail? Attachement file is located on different server (own username/password access)

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
mail_content = """ This is body content """

sender_addr = "sender_addr@server.com"
sender_pass = "apassword"
receiver_addr = "receiver_addr@server.com"

# Create MIME header
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_addr
msg['To'] = receiver_addr
msg['Subject'] = 'A test mail subject sent by Python'
msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))

fname = "doc_1.pdf"
attach_file = open(fname, 'rb')  # **<- How can I specify the remote path here?**
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
# Attach an attachment to payload
payload.set_payload((attach_file).read())
encoders.encode_base64(payload)  

# Add payload header with filename
payload.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=fname)
msg.attach(payload)

# Create SMTP client
client = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
client.starttls()                              
client.login(sender_addr, sender_pass)      
text = msg.as_string()                     

client.sendmail(sender_addr, receiver_addr, text)
client.quit()
print('Mail sent!')
```

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Adding stuff to the question would be fine but changing it so it asks about something else than the answers reply to is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2110#section-4.1 explains the `Content-Location:` header.

Assuming the content you want to link to is in the variable `attach_uri`, something like

```py
# Create MIME header
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_addr
msg['To'] = receiver_addr
msg['Subject'] = 'A test mail subject sent by Python'
msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))

payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
payload.add_header('Content-Location', attach_uri)
msg.attach(payload)
```

If you are asking how to *retrieve* stuff from a remote location and include it in an email, that's a pretty broad topic; but assuming you have the content on an HTTP server, try something like

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(attachment_uri)

payload.set_payload(r.content)
```

before you `msg.attach(payload)`.

With this, there should be no need to set the `Content-Location:` to the original URI any longer (why would the user care where it came from? And you don't want to reveal the password etc).

Comment: Simply link to an existing resource.

Comment: Then how does your script receive the link to the resource?

Comment: The attachment file is located at a remote server like this: username@192.168.10.100:/path/to/dir/remote_file.txt (password is also known)

And I want to include this remote attachement file in the SMTP mail as well.

Comment: You mean your actual question is how to *retrieve* content from a remote location? Use `requests` or similar just like you would for downloading the content to a local disk.

Comment: Should I use some means to 1) download the remote file to local server first, then 2) include the downloaded file in the SMPT mail?

Comment: You can fetch it to memory. See updated answer just now.

Comment: You meant to use "requests.get('path/to/remote/file.txt') to download the remote file and then open/include it in the SMTP mail?

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid URI but other than that, yeah.

Comment: It sent an empty attachment file instead. I modified the original code to reflect the latest code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Because that's what the changed code does; that's how I originally interpreted your question (send `Content-Location:` *instead of* embedding the actual attachment). You really should not edit your question to move the goalposts. And the URI is still wrong;
a valid URI has a protocol specifier like `http://` in front of the host name.

Comment: Question 1) Can I embed an attachment file (located remotely) to SMTP email by specifying its remote path? Question 2) If remote path is like root_user@192.168.100.10:/root/example.txt (for example), how can I convert this path to URI?

Comment: Didn't I already answer exactly these questions? Your remote path doesn't specify a protocol so we can't know if it should have `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://` or something else in front of it. Maybe it's `scp`? (The colon after the host name looks vaguely like an `scp` path, in which case I guess find a question about how to fetch things over `scp` in Python. My first Google hit is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)