# scp command in python script doesn't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I have a problem for several days. On my Raspberry Pi I go to the terminal for executing the following command:

```
scp user@subdomain.server.com:/home/path/to/file/test.py /home/pi/update/test.py
```

It works fine and copies the file from the server without password (because of ssh-keys) to my local machine.

BUT: I have to do exactly the same within a python script:

```
import os
cmd = 'scp user@subdomain.server.com:/home/path/to/file/test.py /home/pi/update/test.py'
os.system(cmd)
```

This doesn't work giving an error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname subdomain.server.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Why do I get this message and especially how can I solve it? Does anyone give an advice, please? I don't understand it ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scp in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried different things with paramiko, pssh, scp, ... and all won't work.

Comment: One problem is that my "pip-installed"-modules can be found locally in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages but the import in my python script can't found them. So I copied them to the script folder ... that helped. But I can't get any connection.