# how to perform ssh and scp equivalent function in python code

Tags: python, automation, ssh, scp

I want to login in different machine in the network and copy a file from that machine to my machine.I want to do this using python.Any idea how can i do this .I have python 2.5 a nd ubuntu 8.10

Comment: Or this one, with different constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh

Comment: there is scp in python to 

from where i can download that module

Comment: @Amit: indeed, it is a dup.

Answer (score 5):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-subprocess.html) and call `scp` directly. This has the advantage of using your ssh settings, private keys and agent.

Look into [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) if you need a more structured framework for doing local and remote operations.

Answer (score 0):

get [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) or similar libraries.

Comment: i have install paramiko but when type import paramiko in python shell
it gives me error

 ImportError
"No module named Crypto.Util.randpool"
File: /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/paramiko/rng.py,

Then i downloaded the PyCrypto tar but it is not installing up