# using scp in a python script on opensolaris

Tags: python

I have written a python script to transfer files/folders between two machines. I have used `scp` for this and have included it as `import scp`
but it's giving me this error:

```
ImportError: No module named scp.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `import` is for importing other python modules, not running external commands.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused...
Did it ever work before?

It seems like you just want to write a python script that calls the scp *command*, not a module.

In which case, do the following:

1. remove the import,
2. and just [execute a simple command from your python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `/path/to/scp.py` is not in your [`${PYTHONPATH}`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.You can either move `scp.py` to somewhere within `${PYTHONPATH}` or augment `${PYTHONPATH}` to include `/path/to` either in your operating system or using [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.path) in Python.

See also [How do I copy a file to a remote server in python using scp or ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install scp
```

Run the above command and then run the script again.