# error when exec'ing scp from python

Tags: python, ssh, scp

this code is giving following error:

```
os.system("scp %s:/export/home/sample/backup.sql  %s:/home/rushi/abc.sql" % (a, b))

Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection
```

a and b are the command line arguments which accept user name and machine name as arguments:

eg: root@10.88.77.77 .

Comment: Looks like an ssh error, nothing to do with python.

Comment: add an ssh tag to the question ;-)

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with Python and everything to do with SSH.

> Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

It's telling you you have failed to log in. I suggest you either sort your key-based auth out or pass it a password.

See: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1

Or instead of trying to use the `scp` command, use [a pure-python method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh/69596#69596).

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from scp.  What happens if you run the command yourself?  Are you expecting to use public key to connect or do you have to enter a password?

Comment: i have to enter a password bt after i enter,it gives me this error