# Secure Copy File from remote server via scp and os module in Python

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I'm pretty new to Python and programming. I'm trying to copy a file between two computers via a python script. However the code

```
os.system("ssh " + hostname + " scp " + filepath + " " + user + "@" + localhost + ":" cwd)
```

won't work. I think it needs a password, as descriped in [How to copy a file to a remote server in Python using SCP or SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh). I didn't get any error logs, the file just won't show in my current working directory.

However every other command with `os.system("ssh " + hostname + "command")` or `os.popen("ssh " + hostname + "command")` does work. -> `command = e.g. ls`

When I try
`ssh hostname scp file user@local:directory`
in the commandline it works without entering a password.

I tried to combine `os.popen` commands with getpass and pxssh module to establish a ssh connection to the remote server and use it to send commands directly (I only tested it for an easy command):

```
import pxssh
import getpass

ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
ssh.force_password = True
hostname = raw_input("Hostname: ")
user = raw_input("Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
ssh.login(hostname, user, password)
test = os.popen("hostname")
print test
```

But I'm not able to put commands through to the remote server (`print test` shows, that hostname = local and not the remote server), however I'm sure, the conection is established. I thought it would be easier to establish a connection than always use `"ssh " + hostname` in the bash commands. I also tried some of the workarounds in [How to copy a file to a remote server in Python using SCP or SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-do-i-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh), but I must admit due to lack of expirience I didn't get them to work.

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do `ssh hostname scp`? Why not just `scp user@hostname:file localdirectory`?

Comment: Prefer the `subprocess` module over `os.system()` for security reasons.

Comment: I haven't thought about the posibility to copy via `scp user@hostname:file localdirectory`. It does work, but only when I cancel the `user@` part.

Comment: I didn't know the `subprocess` module until now, but I will take it into consideration (as I said I'm new to python and learning, I need some time to adopt)

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest (to avoid having to enter a password) and most secure way to go about this is to first set [public/private key authentication](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html). Once that is done, and you can log in to the remote system by doing `ssh user@hostname`, the following bash command would do the trick:

```
scp some/complete/path/to/file user@remote_system:some/remote/path
```

The corresponding Python code would be:

```
import subprocess

filepath = "some/complete/path/to/file"
hostname = "user@remote_system"
remote_path = "some/remote/path"

subprocess.call(['scp', filepath, ':'.join([hostname,remote_path])])
```