# How to copy file from remote Windows to local Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, winrm

I need to copy a file automatically, by Python script.

On remote Windows I have WinRM connection.

So, I can open session like
https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm

I need to copy from path `C:\1.txt` to path `/home/test/1.txt`.

How can I do it (without Ansible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be exactly what you're looking for, SCP over Python script: [How to copy a file to a remote server in Python using SCP or SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-to-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh)

SCP can copy from Windows -> Linux vice versa

Comment: Windows. There is normal winrm-connection, I don't want to add ssh very-very-very much.