# Read and write file over SSH in python 3.5

Tags: python, ssh, python-3.5

I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to read a file from a remote server over ssh and then writing a similar file in the same way. Paramiko doesn't seem to work with 3.5 and i'm not sure what else i can do.

Example of what i'm trying to do:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile('10.1.1.5:v3/ec/s//01_inventory.txt', '10.1.1.5:v3/ec/s//01_inventory_Bkup.txt')
```

Comment: You could use subprocess to call scp via command like I suppose (https://ss64.com/bash/scp.html)

Comment: @Outis How might i implement that into my python program? are these just CLI commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file to a remote server in Python using SCP or SSH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-to-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh)

Comment: Why doesn't Paramiko work with 3.5?

Comment: @Alastair McCormack says no module named Paramiko found

Comment: You need to install it. See http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use scp I suppose (https://ss64.com/bash/scp.html). You would have something like this to replace your copyfile call:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("scp 10.1.1.5:v3/ec/s/01_inventory.txt 10.1.1.5:v3/ec/s/01_inventory_Bkup.txt", shell=True)
```

You could also use scp to copy to your local host, modify it as you would normally and then replace the original.