# pandas read csv file from remote server?

Tags: pandas

I have several servers running the same program. This program will output a csv file, which record the importance results.

I want to load it in my laptop to handle. I can ssh to this server.

so, Is there any methods for `pandas` can load remote file? for example:

```
pd.read_csv("root@1.2.3.4:/data/xxx.csv")
```

p.s. `ssh root@1.2.3.4` works

Answer (score 1):

While it's not possible to directly load a CSV file from a remote server using `pandas`, you can transfer the file to your local machine before loading it, or read it into a buffer using SSH and then use `pandas` to load from that buffer.

You could use scp to transfer the file to your local system and then load it with `pandas`. The first step is to copy the file, which you can do from the command line (not directly within Python):

```bash
scp root@1.2.3.4:/data/xxx.csv /local/path
```

Once the file is on your local system, you can read it with `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/local/path/xxx.csv')
```

An alternative approach is to read the file into memory using a Python package such as `paramiko` that allows for SSH connections and operations in your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such command in Pandas.

If your file is not to large the easiest way to do this would be to copy it locally in memory or on disk. There is an example of how to use SCP to copy files in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335/how-to-copy-a-file-to-a-remote-server-in-python-using-scp-or-ssh), [here](https://gist.github.com/magnologan/ae545777aa9352771852d1725a9bf40c) and [here](https://medium.com/@keagileageek/paramiko-how-to-ssh-and-file-transfers-with-python-75766179de73) all using Paramiko.

Otherwise there are many other way to do this but its hard to give advise with out more details about the project. File size, connection speed, how often the workflow is run ect. And example of such an option would be [SSHFS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the docs for `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). It supports several URL schemes, so if you could, say, run an FTP server on the remote hosts, you could do it that way.