# Recursively copy files by file extension to remote sever

Tags: linux, recursion, scp

I want to copy all file `*.txt` to remote server.
I tried:

`find . -name '*.txt' -exec scp {} user@server:directory ";"`

but it `ask for the password` each time a file found.

Do you have any idea to do this better?
Thank you very much.

Comment: how about `scp \`find . -name *.txt\` user@server:directory`

Comment: or how about `ssh-copy-id server`, followed by original `find . -name ...`

Comment: @jsp: it does not work :(

Comment: If you need to do things like that often, it's also worth to learn how to use `rsync`

Comment: @Hoa Vu which one? ssh-copy-id or scp with backticks?

Comment: @jsp: Could you please specify command with ssh-copy-id. I've not use this before.

Comment: [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) shows you how to setup passwordless scp

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try our `grep` with `ls`:

```
scp `/bin/ls |grep '.txt'` user@destination:/path/to/copy/
```

It will ask for the password only once ;-)

UPDATE:
for recursive copying, `tree` can be used  (it has to be installed first)

```
scp `tree -if --noreport .|grep ".txt"` user@destination:/path/to/copy/
```

Comment: this does not include subdirectories, better to use `scp \`find . -name ...` as in comment above

Comment: @jsp: you're absolutely right. but it return "find . -name *.txt: No such file or directory"

Comment: But does he want recursive copy?

Comment: @Hoa Vu oops forgot single quotes around '*.txt'

Comment: @Hoa Vu `scp \`find . -name '*.txt'\` user@server:directory`

Comment: Updated my answer for recursive copy!

Comment: The problem with `find` is that it would say "cannot read directory x" if the user does not have permission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set private/public key authentication a described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication):
[How do I setup Public-Key Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication)

This way you will never be asked for you user password when scp files to the remote server.