# copying specific files from a server to a local machine using scp-command (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use linux based operating system.
let's say, I have a server contain 10 files like tmp1 .... tmp10, and I want to copy three specific files to my local machine, let's say, tmp3, tmp7 and tmp10. In this case I have to use the "scp-command" three times, where I have to enter the password also three times. the problem is, that I have to do this process so often, so I "wrote" the script below.
My PROBLEM is, that the script runs without any error message, but the files are not copied.

```
echo "insert path of source:" #prompt to enter the path of files you want to copy
read SOURCE                   # saving the path in the variable SOURCE
echo "insert path of target:" #prompt to enter the path, where you want to past the copied files 
read TARGET                   # saving the path in the variable SOURCE
echo "Insert the port"        # prompt to enter the port of the server
read port                     # saving the port in the variable PORT
echo "Password?"              # asking for password
read -s -a PASSWORD           # saving the password in the variable PASSWORD
x=(tmp1 tmp2)                 # An array contains the files i want to copy.
for i in "${x[@]}"            # A for-loop to copy each of the files in the array (x) from the SOURCE to the TARGET
do
  echo "the file $i"          # just to check if the array has been read.
#!/usr/bin/expect -f          # to read the expect-programm
  expect -c " 
            spawn /usr/bin/scp -P $prot $SOURCE/$i $TARGET
            expect { 
           "Password:" { send $PASSWORD\r\n; interact } 
           eof { exit } 
           }
            exit
            "
done                         # End of the for-loop
PASSWORD=0                   # To delete the variable PASSWORD
```

thank you in advance!!

Comment: The proper fix is to set up public-key authentication with the remote host.

Comment: You should probably be quoting the literal strings in the `expect` script; `send \"$PASSWORD\"` etc.

Comment: Why can't you use scp user@host:"/path/tmp{3,7,10}" .? The trick is to quote the path so the expansion is done on the remote machine. That should give you the files you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as scp to copy more than one file. For example:

```
scp remote:tmp{3,7,10} local
```

Answer (score 0):

scp is using ssh for the remote authentication.
There are multiple approaches to handle your issue:
- use ssh agent and set up key based logon - this is more secure. 
There's a howto on setting up ssh to use key based logon in the following link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys
- use the pscp tools that allows you to pass the password to it directly using the -pw argument.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest you use [public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication), so you don't have to worry about passwords in your scripts. Use the `ssh-copy-id` script (at least in Ubuntu) to copy your key to the host you will work on.

I would, as @Joni already mentioned, copy multiple files with one call. Then, if you have to go on with passwords, I would let the `scp` command handle the password prompt.