# Pushing in git using exec with php

Tags: php, git

Any idea how to send the password after the push command?
`exec("git add *");`
`exec("git commit -m 'first commit'");`
`exec("git push origin master")`

Badly needed your advice on how to do this one. 
Any suggestions would highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are a few ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github

Comment: @LajosVeres Where in your link example of *pushing in git using exec* with **php**?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario And it will be straight work? Do you tested it?

Comment: @Victor: the related links could help to send the credentials to git. Otherwise you are right, this is not an exact answer, only a comment.

Comment: What kind of password is needed exactly? SSH credentials?

Comment: @LajosVeres I don't tested your example yet, but I very interested if it work. I think maybe you tested :)

Comment: If you are can use ssh instead of https to connect to your git repo, I'd use (non-interactive) public key authentication. There is also the 'expect' unix programm to handle interactive prompts...

Comment: For ssh, I would also suggest public key auth.

Comment: In this case you could generate a keypair (see 'ssh-keygen' manual) and put your public (!) key in the remote host's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. It's required that the remote ssh server accepts public key authentication (most do). Details are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication

Comment: I user this to generate the key `ssh-keygen -t dsa` . It gives me this one <br> `open /root/.ssh/id_dsa failed: Read-only file system.<br>
Saving the key failed: /root/.ssh/id_dsa.`

Comment: Well this seems to be a misconfiguration of the operating system and probably should be discussed elsewhere (you should NOT be user "root" and your home directory located at something like /home/username). :/