# TCL, expect: Multiple files w/ SCP

Tags: linux, tcl, expect, scp

I was able to transfer files with scp and expect, now I tried to upload several files at once:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Escapes spaces in a text
proc esc text {
    return [regsub -all {\ } $text {\\&}]
}

# Uploads several files to a specified server
proc my_scp_multi {ACCOUNT SERVER PW files newfolder} {
    set timeout 30
    send_user -- "\n"
    spawn scp $files $ACCOUNT@$SERVER:[esc $newfolder]
    match_max 100000
    # Look for password prompt
    expect {
    -re ".*Connection closed.*" {
        sendError "\n\n\nUpload failed!\nPlease check the errors above and start over again.\nThis is most likely induced by too many wrong password-attempts and will last quite a time!"
    }
    -re ".*Permission denied.*" {
        sendError "\n\n\nUpload failed!\nPlease check the errors above and start over again.\nYou entered most likely a wrong password!"
    }
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
        send "yes\n"
        exp_continue
        #look for the password prompt
    }
    -re ".*sword.*" {
        # Send password aka $PW
        send -- "$PW\r"
        # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
        send -- "\r\n"
        exp_continue
    }

    send_user -- "Upload successful!\n"
    }

    set timeout -1
}
```

When I want to upload several files, the sh command is:
`scp $a $b $c user@server:$folder`, so I called `my_scp_multi "ACCOUNT" "SERVER" "PW" "~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC" "~/test/"`. Which also produces this output:

```
spawn scp ~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC user@server:~/test/
user@server's password: 
~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC: No such file or directory
```

It seems to see "~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC" as one file. But when I copy-paste `scp ~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC user@server:~/test/` to the console it works fine!

What am I doing wrong? I've tried `"\"~/testfileA\" \"~/testfileB\" \"~/testfileC\""` and such things, but nothing did work at all.

Any ideas or suggestions?

---

**EDITS**

P.S.: I'm transferring rather small files. Building up a connection is the biggest part of the transfer. This is the reason I want it to be done in ONE scp.

P.P.S.:
I played around a little and came up with:

```
my_scp_multi3 "user" "server" "pw" "~/a\ b/testfileA, ~/a\\ b/testfileB, ~/a\\\ b/testfileC" "~/test"
```

with your first solution but `{*}[split $files ","]` and

```
my_scp_multi2 "user" "server" "pw" "~/a b/testfileA" "~/a\ b/testfileB" "~/a\\ b/testfileC" "~/test"
```

with your second solution. This prints:

```
~/a b/testfileA: No such file or directory
~/a\ b/testfileB: No such file or directory
~/a\ b/testfileC: No such file or directory
```

and

```
~/a b/testfileA: No such file or directory
~/a b/testfileB: No such file or directory
~/a\ b/testfileC: No such file or directory
```

*(BTW: I of course moved the files :) )*

---

Thanks to all the answers, here my **Solution**:

using <del>\n</del> \0 (nullbyte) as separator, because it is the only symbol except / and \ which may not be used in filenames.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

    # Escapes spaces in a text
    proc esc text {
        return [regsub -all {\ } $text {\\&}]
    }

# Returns the absolute Filepath
proc makeAbsolute {pathname} {
    file join [pwd] $pathname
}

proc addUploadFile {files f} {
    if {$files != ""} {
        set files "$files\0"
    }
    return "$files[makeAbsolute $f]"
}

#Counts all files from an upload-list
proc countUploadFiles {s} {
        set rc [llength [split $s "\0"]] 
        incr rc -1
        return $rc
 }

# Uploads several files from a list (created by addUploadFile) to a specified server
proc my_scp_multi {ACCOUNT SERVER PW files newfolder} {
    foreground blue
    set nFiles [countUploadFiles $files]
    set timeout [expr $nFiles * 60]
        send_user -- "\n"
        spawn scp -r {*}[split $files "\0"] $ACCOUNT@$SERVER:[esc $newfolder]
        match_max 100000
        # Look for password prompt
        expect {
        -re ".*Connection closed.*" {
            sendError "\n\n\nUpload failed!\nPlease check the errors above and start over again.\nThis is most likely induced by too many wrong password-attempts and will last quite a time!"
        }
        -re ".*Permission denied.*" {
            sendError "\n\n\nUpload failed!\nPlease check the errors above and start over again.\nYou entered most likely a wrong password!"
        }
        -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
            send "yes\n"
            exp_continue
            #look for the password prompt
        }
        -re ".*sword.*" {
            # Send password aka $PW
            send -- "$PW\r"
            # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
            send -- "\r\n"
            exp_continue
        }

        send_user -- "Upload successful!\n"
        }

        set timeout -1
    }



set fls [addUploadFile "" "a b/testfileA"]
set fls [addUploadFile $fls "a b/testfileB"]
set fls [addUploadFile $fls "a b/testfileC"]

my_scp_multi "user" "server" "pw" $fls "~/test"
```

Comment: technically, the directory separator and the null byte `\0` are the only characters disallowed from a filename. Newline is a valid filename character. Try it in bash: `touch $'a\nfile\nname'`. This very fact causes shell script writers and tool developers plenty of headaches: it's why GNU find has a `-print0` directive, xargs has `-0`, etc, etc

Comment: This is pain! So you'd suggest just using \0 instead of \n ?

Comment: why are you constructing a string and then splitting it? Just use a list in the first place: `foreach f {"a b/A" "a b/B" "a b/C"} {lappend fls [makeAbsolute $f]}; ... spawn ... {*}$files ...`

Comment: Absolutely right. Hmmm works now and I'm too lazy to change it.

Comment: hmm, now you know what the "pain" feels like, you're OK with it?

Comment: I will need to be okay w/ it :D I think there still is something I don't really get. For instance, when I login to a server via ssh and then `send` a lpr-Command like `lpr a b.pdf` or `lpr a\ b.pdf` or `lpr a\\ b.pdf` or `lpr a\\\ b.pdf` nothing will work. Again, when I c&p the code into the console it'll work? Doesnt tcl just send the command as text?

Comment: Hehe, nice work with `lpr 'a b.pdf'`. But I still don't get why the command does not work, when the copied one does.

Comment: because Tcl is not sh. Use "double quotes" or {braces} for grouping instead of relying on escaping spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to send the filenames as a single string. Either do this:

```
spawn scp {*}[split $files] $ACCOUNT@$SERVER:[esc $newfolder]
```

And continue to quote the filenames:

```
my_scp_multi "ACCOUNT" "SERVER" "PW" "~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC" "~/test/"
```

**or** do this:

```
proc my_scp_multi {ACCOUNT SERVER PW args} {
    set timeout 30
    send_user -- "\n"
    set files [lrange $args 0 end-1]
    set newfolder [lindex $args end]
    spawn scp {*}$files $ACCOUNT@$SERVER:[esc $newfolder]
```

And then do *not* quote the filenames

```
my_scp_multi "ACCOUNT" "SERVER" "PW" ~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC "~/test/"
```

The splat (`{*}`) splits the list up into it's individual elements so the spawn command sees several words, not a single word. See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! This works very good. So the scp here is a tcl-command and not the "normal" shell scp?

Comment: Because scp was looking for a single file named `~/testfileA ~/testfileB ~/testfileC` (with the spaces), and it could not find one. You need to provide scp with individual filenames, and you want this special Tcl syntax to do it.

Comment: Okay, that's running great! Just one problem remains: spaces in file names; Either one of your solutions does not work. See more in my post.

Comment: That's because you're inserting a literal backslash into the filename. Just quoting suffices: `my_scp_multi2 "user" "server" "pw" "~/a b/testfileA" "~/a b/testfileB" "~/a b/testfileC" "~/test"`

Comment: Even `"~/a b/testfileA" "~/a\ b/testfileB" "~/a\\ b/testfileC"` produces the same error for all three files...

Comment: it may be that the `~` is not being expanded. Do `cd` before spawn, and use `"a b/testfileA" "a b/testfileB" "a b/testfileC"`

Comment: Yes, it indeed was. Funny, as target (and for single files) it works with ~... Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You could spawn a shell and then run the scp command instead:

```
spawn bash
send "scp $files $ACCOUNT@$SERVER:[esc $newfolder]\r"
```

This allows for glob expansion but adds extra housekeeping as you will need to trap when the scp process is completed, as you still have a shell running. 
You could add below to your expect block:

```
-re "100%" {
    if { $index < $count } {
        set index [expr $index + 1]
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

Where index is the # of file being transferred and count the nr of files.

Comment: Good idea, but sounds rather complicated, compared to glenn's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using SSH public key authentication instead of typing in the password with `expect`.  When it's set up properly, `scp` will work without any human input of passwords while keeping the system very secure.  You will be free from all the troubles with `expect`.

- [How do I setup Public-Key Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication)
- http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

<del>If there's some reason why you cannot use pubkey, you may find `sftp` useful because it accepts a batch command file as `-b batchfile`.  See `man 1 sftp`</del> Not a very good solution when `expect` can actually split the arguments

Comment: Thank you! There actually is a reason why I can not (and don't want to) use public key auth. sftp might have been a solution, but glenn's answer is easier, I think.