# rsync: how to authenticate user to the remote side

Tags: linux, authentication, rsync

I was writing a script that uses rsync. The problem that I'm facing is how to authenticate the user to the remote side. It seems that the only approaches to provide the password is to use the RSYNC_PASSWORD env var, or to use the --password-file option. What I'm think is that use something like "--password=

Comment: Usually rsync uses ssh. Use ssh key authentication.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication

Answer (score 0):

You need to user **sshpass** try following command

```
sshpass -p password rsync "your remaining command"
```

if **sshpass** is not installed then install it.