# Got an error while executing bash commands on remote ubuntu machine "no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I'm running a bash script to execute a command on a remote host. Here is the command:

```
ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "sudo mv /tmp/$2.tar.gz $1"
```

`$1` and `$2` are command line arguments. But while executing I'm getting this error : no tty present and no askpass program specified.

Hope you will help me, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: It seems that you need to set up ssh key authentication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your sudoers file you have following

```
Defaults requiretty
```

Just comment this line - remove it. Or

```
Defaults !requiretty
```

For specific program name you can also attempt following:

```
Defaults </path to program> requiretty
```

change it to

```
Defaults </path to program> ! requiretty
```

Specific to user you can add

```
Defaults:username !requiretty
```

Adding What already have been specified in comment,
For the same you will have to

```
user-name    ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Its for passwordless sudo

Comment: Hi, Jord, Thanks for the help, I checked on the /etc/sudores file, but the "Defaults requiretty" already have been removed, but still getting the same error, any other thing to do? , hope u eill help, Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried after removing every entry for tty
    `Defaults !requiretty`
basically two things are required to run cmd on remote the way you are doing 1) requiretty removed 2) and NOPASSWD sudo for user with which you are connecting remotely.

Comment: Hello Jord, Thanks for the help, after adding NOPASSWD after the sudo on sudores file, it worked. I'll edit ur answer thank you..so..much... :)

Comment: @user3440631 how about accepting it as a soulution thn :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are invoking sudo, and it is not working because it doesn't have a tty bound. add

```
"Defaults visiblepw"
```

in sudoers file enables sudo even if a console doesn't allocate a tty. Use visudo on the remote machine to add this and see if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command

```
sshpasss -p password ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "sudo mv /tmp/$2.tar.gz $1"
```

Comment: Hello @Rahul, I have already added public key to the remotehost(10.101.5.91) so i need to execute the command without the password. So hope u will help, thank You.... :)

Comment: The OP is successfully authenticating through ssh. The error is coming from sudo. You also misspelled "sshpass".