# Python code, does subprocess work with glob?

Tags: python, sftp

the short of it is that i need a program to upload all txt files from a local directory via sftp, to a specific remote directory. if i run mput *.txt from sftp command line, while im already in the right local directory, then that was what i was shooting for.

Here is the code im trying. No errors when i run it, but no results either when i sftp to the server and ls the upload directory, its empty. i may be barking up the wrong tree all together. i see other solutions like lftp using mget in bash...but i really want this to work with python. either way i have a lot to learn still. this is what ive come up with after a few days reading about what some stackoverflow users suggested, a few libraries that might help. im not sure i can do the "for i in allfiles:" with subprocess.

```
import os
import glob
import subprocess 

os.chdir('/home/submitid/Local/Upload') #change pwd so i can use mget *.txt and glob similarly 

pwd = '/Home/submitid/Upload' #remote directory to upload all txt files to

allfiles = glob.glob('*.txt') #get a list of txt files in lpwd

target="user@sftp.com"


sp = subprocess.Popen(['sftp', target], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


sp.stdin.write("chdir %s\n" % pwd) #change directory to pwd

for i in allfiles:
    sp.stdin.write("put %s\n" % allfiles) #for each file in allfiles, do a put %filename to pwd

sp.stdin.write("bye\n")       


sp.stdin.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over `allfiles`, you are not passing the iterator variable `sp.stdin.write`, but `allfiles` itself. It should be

```
for i in allfiles:
    sp.stdin.write("put %s\n" % i) #for each file in allfiles, do a put %filename to pwd
```

You may also need to wait for `sftp` to authenticate before issuing commands. You could read stdout from the process, or just put some `time.sleep` delays in your code.

But why not just use `scp` and build the full command line, then check if it executes successfully? Something like:

```
result = os.system('scp %s %s:%s' % (' '.join(allfiles), target, pwd))
if result != 0:
    print 'error!'
```

Comment: DANG that worked! Now if i can only get rid of the password prompt. i will have to read up on the time.sleep...thank you!!

Comment: @Dogbyte you might be better off just using SSH public key authentication to bypass the need for a password. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication

Comment: about the SSH public key auth, im not sure i have that level of access to the remote server, this is an EDI transaction to a healthcare provider. they only allow the basic sftp commands.

Comment: im not sure what the scp line is doing, i just started coding a few weeks ago, is that result line only handling connecting to the sftp server? ' '.join(allfiles) is just passing the list of files?

Comment: `sftp` and `scp` both transfer files using SSH, so you should be able to get it to work. `' '.join(allfiles)` joins a list of strings with a space `' '`.

Comment: The `scp` command expands to `scp 1.txt 2.txt user@sftp.com:/Home/submitid/Upload`. This just instructs `scp` to copy the text files to the remote server in one simple command.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to iterate over `allfiles`

```
sp.stdin.write("put *.txt\n")
```

is enough. You instruct sftp to put all files at once, instead of one by one.